# android hprof files in project src

Tags: android, android-studio, hprof

I have an android project on my C:/ drive which Android Studio points to.
I have noticed that when i Zip up the project folder, it has gone from say 20 MB to 42 GB. There are lots of hprof files.

I have looked at some posts and i do not want to use the hprof view  or look at how the app is performing. i just want to delete these files.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html

my question is, can i just delete all these files from the project folder directly before zipping the folder?

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can delete them, they are only used for viewing memory dumps and not needed to build the app.

Comment: Something, though, is causing these to appear beyond just taking a heap dump, at least with Android Studio 2.3.3. On a project that I am working on, where I have never taken a heap dump, I was stunned to find two of these files in the project root, clocking in at over 1GB apiece.

Comment: @CommonsWare Exactly Mark, i upgraded to AS 2.3.3 about 3 months ago and never had this problem. Never taken a heap dump either. Ok great, I'll just delete them.